# Loop through array and apply text to n:th element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an array like so: `["abc", "cde", "efg"]`.

I want to loop through a set of elements and apply the strings from this array to each n:th (the length of the array) element.

```
<p>abc</p>
<p>cde</p>
<p>efg</p>
```

All I've managed is how to loop and apply the same string (the last one) to each element like:

```
<p>efg</p>
<p>efg</p>
<p>efg</p>
```

EDIT:

Currently I'm working with something like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < noOfTableCells.length; j++) {
            var heading = "";
            for (var k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++) {
                heading = headingArray[k];
            }
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to every n:th (3rd in this case) element.

Comment: Please provide your existing code.

Comment: What does it mean to *apply* a string?

Comment: j += 3 does unfortunately not do the trick, I still want to apply something to each element, but alternate between the 3 values.

Comment: Well, it gives you every third element. It's not clear (at least to me) what exactly you want. Are the elements in the document already, or are you creating them? What is the wanted result in the example? I.e. how are you using `heading` variable? Perhaps there are more elements than the length of the array, and you want to fill elements starting over the array from the beginning when all members are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it with the following:

```
var laps = totalItems / myArray.length;

for (var row = 0; row < laps; row++) {
            for (var cell = 0; cell < myArray.length; cell++) {
                //Do the stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When looping through the other elements, if there is a numbering system associated with that, you can use the numbering system. Otherwise, you can loop through those elements with a C-style for loop, as follows:

```
var myArray = ["abc", "cde", "efg"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var j = i % 3;
    j = (i - j) + 2;
    //do something with the element that you wanted
    //do something with myArray[j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vL1npq/):

```
var elements = ["abc", "cde", "efg"].map(function(str) {
    return '<p>' + str + '</p>';
});

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    $('body').append(element);
});
```

Or you could shorten it:

```
["abc", "cde", "efg"].map(function(str) {
    return '<p>' + str + '</p>';
}).forEach(function(element) {
    $('body').append(element);
});
```

This uses jQuery. If you want to be a super random badass, you can do this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vL1npq/1/)):

```
var elements = ["abc", "cde", "efg"].map(function(str) {
    return '<p>' + str + '</p>';
}),
    parser = new DOMParser();

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    document.body.appendChild(parser.parseFromString(element, "text/xml").firstChild);
});
```

There are a 1000 other random, or 1000 other more efficient, solutions to this. Pick your poison.